# How can I see the background image on my iPhone?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, mobile

Im making a mobile website with jQuery Mobile, HTML and CSS and Im trying to add a bakground image. On my computer I can see it, its fully visible and reacting when Im making changes but when I test it on my iPhone there is no image. I cant see it.
I know the phone is fully connected and all because text and other things I can change.
Anyone know how to solve this?
This is the CSS-code:

```
body {
    background: transparent url(Images/phoneWallpaper.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:scroll;

}

.ui-page {
    background: transparent;

}​

.ui-content{
    background: transparent;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add some vendor prefixes to the background `CSS`

This article may help: [Here](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/01/developing-a-responsive-website-background-images/)

To check what prefixes you may need, you can run your `CSS` code through `Prefixr`: [Here](http://prefixr.com/)